# Ubuntu 14.04 / desktop / startup

Tags: startup

I'am using Ubuntu 14.04 / desktop as a controller for our WiFi service, to be able to run the controller SW I need to run the following command in terminal:

```
java -jar Desktop/UniFi/lib/ace.jar start
```

Is it possible to run this command on starup in case the pc needs rebooting? so I don't need to run it every time after rebooting the system.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **/etc/rc.local**:

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

and add your command before the *exit 0*

Comment: Hi iffy,many thanks for your quick reply, I've done it but didn't work :-( sorry.  Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: 1. does your rc.local file have the #!/bin/sh -e in it? 2. does the rc.local file have execute permissions? 3. does the jar file require root permissions to run? 4. does that jar file require the X server to run in order for it to execute?